# Rails3: How to use the asset pipeline to build static assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

So I started investigating the asset pipeline in Rails3 and I have a desired use case that is somewhat off the beaten path...  so I'm looking for a recipe.

- I often run webrick locally for development and then run
  Passenger+Apache for deployed instances of the app.
- the app is configured with a suburi path, e.g. http:// server/approot/...
- to make webrick paths work like deployed instances, I added `map '/approot' do run app` to `config.ru`.  Now webrick is also at http:// local:3000/approot/...

## The Confusion

Given this setup, I tried to use `rake assets:precompile` and have been having a lot of configuration problems between local, deployed -- missing files, incorrect paths, 404s in firebug, etc.  Here's a smattering of solutions I've tried:

- `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` to `application.rb` to prevent trying to initialize the app for `production`, (we have several deployed environments and call them different names, ug.) when precompiling the assets.
- `config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css )` to `application.rb` to include things like jquery.js and ujs and rails.js that were missing.
- `config.assets.prefix = "/approot/assets"` to correct a problem where the map above (in config.ru) doesn't apply to assets, so assets had to be precompiled to `./public/approot/assets`, but I'm not sure if that only works locally, i.e. if I deploy, will my asset paths be `http:// server/approot/approot/(js|css|...)`?

When precompiling assets, the rake task switches to env `production`, but then it is unclear from the Rails3 doc whether sprockets continues to compile on the fly locally and use those dynamic assets, or whether it will serve the static precompiled assets instead?

- I tried putting `config.serve_static_assets = true` in `environments/development.rb`, but I'm not sure how this works with `config.assets.compress = false` and `config.assets.debug = true`.  Setting the assets.debug to false just seems to hide the GET requests in the webrick log, although I saw a post saying that "solved the problem" [sic].

## Requirments for a Recipe

So I'd like a recipe that does the following:

- **assets are consistently and correctly served from a path** `http://server/approot/assets/...` whether run in passenger or webrick (i.e. deployed or local). If this isn't possible, then I can switch my local dev environment to use Passenger+Apache as well, it's not a big deal, but I just want to know if it's possible.
- raw assets exist in `/app/assets` like normal Rails3, but when I precompile them, they work exactly the same way in deployed envs so that **asset file references don't break** (i.e. right now, there are a lot of refs looking for `/assets/image/...` when the path is clearly set up as `/approot/assets/image...`. (It's unclear from the Rails3 doc whether there are assumptions about deploying to root vs a suburi, e.g. `http:// server/assets/...` vs. `http:// server/approot/assets/...`)
- **sprockets can't be used in deployed environments** (our restriction, sorry).  So this means the rails3 app has to effectively look like a static asset app.  I know this is what precompiled assets are supposed to do, but the pathing issues are preventing me from getting this working as advertised.

---

TL;DR - I feel like I'm trying a lot of separate things that might work if I only knew the right combination of them.

## References

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets
- http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/02/untangling-the-rails-asset-pipeline-part-2-production/
- http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/02/untangling-the-rails-asset-pipeline-part-3-configuration/
- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3946

Comment: If you're using Sprockets to compile assets ahead of time, you need Sprockets to read the manifest again later; it all flows through [Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb). If you can't use Sprockets in production ("our restriction, sorry"), you should rip it out in development too.

Comment: Yeah, I got that impression the more I read about it and how the pieces fit together.  Thanks! We don't have a lot of flexibility in how we set up our apps -- another team manages Apache and Passenger in deployed envs, but using sprockets in the rails app might be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a potentially *horrible answer*, but it seems to work with webrick in two contexts now and it's the day after Halloween (although I haven't tried this approach in deployed slots yet).

## Configuration

Unless otherwise mentioned, everything is defaults from a `rails new app` generation.

**config/application.rb**

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

**environments/production.rb** *(not really production, only used for rake asset:precompile)*

```
config.assets.css_compressor = :yui
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

**environments/stage.rb** *(this is one of our deployed envs)*

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

**config.ru**

This is the *horrible part*.  I duplicated the map so that Rack would serve both the suburi and the root.  So the controller action that shows the layout can have `http:// server/approot/foo/index`, while the assets within the layout can be loaded from `http:// server/assets/...`

```
map '/approot' do
  run AppRoot::Application
end

map '/' do
  run AppRoot::Application
end
```

## Running it locally

```
$ rake assets:precompile
$ rails s
```

and in firebug I see the separate parts served by sprockets (all 200 OK):

- GET /approot/
- GET /assets/application.css?body=1
- GET /assets/jquery.js?body=1
- GET /assets/jquery.ujs.js?body=1
- GET /assets/application.js?body=1

Ok, so now test a 'deployed' slot locally and see if the compiled assets work?

$ rails s -e stage

and then I see the correct precompiled assets (all 200 OK):

- GET /approot/
- GET /assets/application-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.css
- GET /assets/application-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.js

Ok, so this isn't as nice as a real suburi solution and I think I'm going to have problems in deployed slots.  Round 2, fight!